# SQLAlchemy: When Creating INSERT Query, Occured CompileError "Uncosumed column names"

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Envirionment:
SQLAlchemy + PostgreSQL (pg8000)

Situation:
I created two table from psql console.

```sql
CREATE TABLE testidtable(
  testid BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE testidtable2(
  testid bigint PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT testid_is_valid FOREIGN KEY(testid) REFERENCES testidtable (testid)
);
```

Here is the python code:

```py
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData

from config import Config

conf = Config()
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create(
        "postgresql+pg8000",
        database="databasename",
        username=conf.db1_user,
        password=conf.db1_pass),
    client_encoding='utf-8')
metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(bind=engine)

engine.connect()
table1 = Table("testidtable", metadata, autoload_with=engine)
ins1 = table1.insert().values({})
ret1 = engine.execute(ins1)
testid = ret1.inserted_primary_key[0]
table2 = Table("testidtable2", metadata, autoload_with=engine)
ins2 = table2.insert().values({"testid":testid})
ret2 = engine.execute(ins2)
```

And the error occurred:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Unconsumed column names: testid
```

I tried to show `ins2` which is INSERT query for debugging, but faced the same situation.

How can I do INSERT `testid` into `testidtable2` successfully?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't reproduce, no error when I run this code (I connected using a Unix socket rather than user/password, but that should make no difference).

Comment: Thanks for checking.
I agree that no difference between user/password and Unix socket.
Could you please try to print the content of `ins2`?

Comment: `INSERT INTO testidtable2 (testid) VALUES (:testid)`  or `INSERT INTO testidtable2 (testid) VALUES (2)` with bound value.

Comment: Thanks. These values are same as what my expected. I'll check my environment and add-ons.

Comment: I finally figured out that my `CONSTRAINT` clause in other tables were wrong.